# exclamation mark in registry value

Tags: batch-file, command-line, registry

I have a problem when I tried to update via batch file registry key as follows:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d "vovaogova!"
```

but the exclamation mark is missing when I check it!!
I know that there is meaning of exclamation mark in the path but what about the value?

Comment: Have you got [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled while executing your command line?

Comment: yes. should I remove this line?

Comment: Delayed expansion consumes exclamation marks, so yes, remove it…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As as  [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) said.

I removed  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion from my script and it works!!

Comment: Please edit the question and not post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using an escape character: `^`

Like that: `REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d "vovaogova^!"`

For me, it adds the caret, but, try that.